# Node.js localhost to live server

Tags: node.js, npm, server

Hello dear developers.

I have been working on a game, and that game is finished and ready to be exported/shared. I have used Typescript/ npm / node.js. My question is how can I turn my node.js game from a http://localhost:8000/ to live server, so I can share it. I have tried to come up with a possible fix or solution, but its been a month now and I still find no success. Im new and tried reading many forums. I read about the node_modules, they have something to do with this but im totally lost at this point. There are also things called dependencies. My Teacher told me the game had to be exported in such a way that the receiving device has to be able to run the game without node or npm being installed on the device. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you edit your question and list some of the things you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a static IP, and a simple http server. It works.

At home I don't have a static IP, it's possible to do it with a 3rd party tool as far as I learned from some tutorials but I did not try.

Comment: That doesn't help me much, and i dont know how to do it either.